# Jupyter Notebook: How to change spacing between Text objects inside HBox?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

Say I have the following code in a cell in the Jupyter Notebook:

```
from ipywidgets.widgets import HBox, Text
from IPython.display import display

text1 = Text(description = "text1", width = 100)
text2 = Text(description = "text2", width = 100)
text3 = Text(description = "text3", width = 100)
text4 = Text(description = "text4", width = 100)
text5 = Text(description = "text5", width = 100)
display(HBox((text1, text2, text3, text4, text5)))
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a ton of unnecessary spacing between the Text objects. How do I change the spacing so that they stay within the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the spacing is due to the width of the `widget-text` class being specified with a width of 350 pixels. Try importing the `HTML` module (i.e. `from IPython.display import display, HTML`) and insert `HTML('<style> .widget-text { width: auto; } </style>')` into the cell.

You should end up with something like this:

```
from ipywidgets.widgets import HBox, Text
from IPython.display import display, HTML

text1 = Text(description = "text1", width = 100)
text2 = Text(description = "text2", width = 100)
text3 = Text(description = "text3", width = 100)
text4 = Text(description = "text4", width = 100)
text5 = Text(description = "text5", width = 100)

display(HBox((text1, text2, text3, text4, text5)))
HTML('<style> .widget-text { width: auto; } </style>')
```

[image: widgets styled with CSS]

Comment: Did you make sure to insert the line after `display(HBox((text1, text2, text3, text4, text5)))`?

Comment: Hey, sorry, one more thing. When I add the additional line "print("HI")" right below the HTML object, the formatting gets messed up again. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I think you should be okay if you place the `HTML('<style> .widget-text { width: auto; } </style>')` line at the end of the cell. Jupyter will override your CSS with the defaults if you place something after that line.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Zarak's answer, you can do something like this

```
from ipywidgets.widgets import HBox, Text
from IPython.display import display, HTML

text1 = Text(description = "text1", width = 100)
text2 = Text(description = "text2", width = 100)
text3 = Text(description = "text3", width = 100)
text4 = Text(description = "text4", width = 100)
text5 = Text(description = "text5", width = 100)

display(HBox((text1, text2, text3, text4, text5)))
display(HTML('<style> .widget-text { width: auto; } </style>'))
print('hi')
```

This way, you don't need to have the `HTML('<style> .widget-text { width: auto; } </style>')` statement as the last statement.